# Bootstap d-md-block causes new row with icon and text in navtabs

Tags: bootstrap-4, tabs

Simple question but is doing my head in. I am using BT4 navtabs and the nav-item has an icon (fontawesome) and text. I want to hide the text only on mobile (not enough space) but if I add a "d-none d-md-block" this causes a new row between the icon and the text.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
        <li class="nav-item ">
             <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users "></i><span 
               class="d-none d-md-block">Active</span></a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

If I remove the d-md-block it goes back to one row again with the icon and text on same. Scratching my head as to how I can do this.

ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **d-md-block** is a block element. Instead of **d-md-block**, you could use **d-md-inline**. Which will solve your problem.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
<li class="nav-item ">    
  <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users "></i><span 
    class="d-none d-md-inline">Active</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked great and shows that I need to read up on the bootstrap docs and learn them better. Cheers.

Comment: Please mark it as the correct answer. So that others can get help from it. Happy coding!!